# Changing the nginx routed url

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to redirect the server from Nginx port 80 to port 9090 on our server. But when Nginx hits the url it rewrites as `http://localhost/assets/css/style.css`. but I want it to redirect as `http://localhost:9090/assets/css/style.css` to access the style.css file.

here is my config code,

```
 location /t3{
                proxy_pass   http://localhost:9090;
                proxy_redirect http://localhost:9090 $scheme://$host:80/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Your location starts with `/t3` - and does not cover URLs like `/assets/.....` You should probably rename the location to just `/`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `proxy_pass` which here nginx acts as a reverse proxy and forwards all requests to the `http://localhost:9090` if you send it to `/t3`. So when a user sends a request like `http://nginx/t3/hi` nginx receives the request and sends it to `http://localhost:9090/t3/hi`. After that, nginx receives the response from `localhost:9090` and sends it back to the client. The user will not see the `localhost:9090`.

What you want is something like request `rewrite`:

```
server{
...
    location /product {
        rewrite ^/product(.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 redirect;
    }
...
}
```

[nginx rewrite rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)